# Conditionally override a view of object in salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am trying to override view action on Task object as I have requirement to validate the contact/Lead address associated with that task before opening the task record. As soon as the contact/lead address are validated , I want to open up that task. I open that task using nooverride=1 in URL for salesforce. But in salesforce1 it enters a infinte loop. Is there any way to load up the standard salesforce1 page layout instead for overridden one ?